# "Cut off" the link between the terminal and a command

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I have created the `pycharm` command in Ubuntu, but I have a little issue. When I execute the command, pycharm opened, but it stayed related to the terminal. I mean if I close the terminal, pycharm will eventually close as well. Is there an easy way to "cut off" this link between the terminal and pycharm? I think it is related to `SIGHUP`, but it is unclear.

Thanks in advance!

Here the content of the `restart.py` script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Waits for the parent process to terminate, then executes specified commands.

import os
import signal
import sys
import time

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    raise Exception('usage: restart.py <pid> <path> [optional command]')

# signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIG_IGN)

pid = int(sys.argv[1])
while os.getppid() == pid:
    time.sleep(0.5)

if len(sys.argv) > 3:

to_launch = ['/usr/bin/open', sys.argv[2]] if sys.platform == 'darwin' else [sy$
os.execv(to_launch[0], to_launch)
```

Comment: Look at the `nohup` shell command.

Comment: I know that command, but I'd like, if possible, just enter the simple command-line `pycharm`.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is an alias, then...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this command

```
nohup pycharm > ~/pycharm.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I almost understand that command. Could you explain what `2>&1 &` means?

Comment: @J.Doe File descriptor `1` is the standard output ,file descriptor `2` is the standard error, and `&`  indicates that what follows is a file descriptor.By running this command stderr will be redirected to stdout.So that means `stderr` will be written to that file.